# Getting html DOM element from JQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code gives me JQuery object, which includes JQuery functions associated with.

```
var element = $("#element");
```

But how can I get the HTML DOM element from the above JQuery object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get (link to API)](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
 element.get()
```

It will return an array.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch first item from jQuery object

```
var element = $("#element")[0];
```